# How do I filter for leaf nodes in an MP_NODE

Tags: django, django-treebeard

I have a tree model for categories like this:

```
from treebeard.mp_tree import MP_Node

class Category(MP_Node):
    ...
```

And I want to get a queryset with only the leaf nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MP_Node` has a field called `numchild`, which stores the amount of children each node has, so you can get a queryset of all leaf nodes like this:

```
Category.objects.filter(numchild=0)
```